# Batch file set wmi output as a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hello having my first go with a BATCH script, I'm getting the size of the HDD as follow:

```
wmic diskdrive get size
```

Which works fine but I'd like to store this value into a variable for later use, such as using ECHO to display the value.

I'm not sure how I set the output of the above command to a variable. I went with:

```
SET hddbytes=wmic diskdrive get size
```

But this just sets the variable to the above text string and not the output.

Comment: I think that all these solutions will give only one drive in the list - mine has a few drives listed.  BTW, this is `batch` script and not `BASH`

Comment: @foxidrive yes of course :) I'm mostly defiantly not a Windows person just have BASH on the mind, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For usage in batch file. From command line, replace %% with %

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('wmic diskdrive get size /value ^| find "="') do set "%%f"
echo %size%
```

Or, if you want to use you prefered variable

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic diskdrive get size /value ^| find "="') do set "myVar=%%f"
echo %myVar%
```

Comment: +1.Would prefer Textvaluelist format and thus `set` could be used directly.

Comment: you can use `"delims="` and `set %%f` directly but this is just the way  I prefer to set values when using wmic

Comment: @npocmaka: Yes. I understand. If you look at the first code in answer, changing `delims=` for `tokens=*` you will have the same solution `set "%%f"`

Comment: For both of these, as-is, in a batch file on Windows 7, I get: `'wmic diskdrive get size /value | find "="' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @ashleedawg, Tested in W10 (five years from the answer, I don't have W7 at hand) and working. Have you checked `wmic` is available in your install? Some problem with `path`?

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic diskdrive get size^|findstr [0-9]') do echo %%a
```

Comment: actually the question is asking about putting it into a variable

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

1. WMIC's output could get a trailing *Carriage Return* in some environment:

   ```
   Size        <CR>
   <CR><LF>
   256052966400<CR>
   <CR><LF>
   500105249280<CR>
   <CR><LF>
   15496427520 <CR>
   <CR><LF>
   ```
2. use csv format, and use FOR loop to truncate the wanted value from the wmic output:

   ```
   For /F "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in ('"wmic diskdrive get size,Status 
   /format:csv |findstr "[0-9]" "') do (
   echo "%%a"
   )
   ```

Another Batch Script Example:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: You can change active code page as well::
@chcp 936 >NUL

:: [example] Remove all network printers:
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in ('"wmic printer where 'local=FALSE' get Name,PrinterStatus /format:csv |findstr "." "') do (
    echo "%%a"
    rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n "%%a" /dn /q
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims="  %%w in ('wmic diskdrive get size /format:Textvaluelist.xsl') do for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ('%%w') do set %%a
echo %size%
```